# Is it possible to make this ASP.NET to ASP.NET SSO functionality work with ASP.NET to PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net, single-sign-on

Here are the instructions to setup SSO between two ASP.NET sites using this web app called SmarterTrack. https://portal.smartertools.com/kb/a2517/configure-single-sign-on-between-smartertrack-and-another-site.aspx

I want to setup SSO between this ST app and a Wordpress site, which is in PHP. Do you think I could use this built-in SSO functionality linked above, or would I need to create an SSO solution from scratch?

Comment: I would use one of the SSO implementations that have already been well documented.  OAuth2, SAML, JWT, CAS and many more are all suitable solutions with libraries implemented in many languages.  The link you provided provides no implementation details, only how to add it to another .net project so you are at their mercy to implement a PHP client.

Comment: Do all SSO solutions actually create new accounts with matching info from the identity provider? Because that's how this SSO works: http://help.smartertools.com/SmarterTrack/current/Default.aspx?qq=%2fSmarterTrack%2fcurrent%2fTopics%2fConcepts%2fSingleSignon.aspx And that's what I want. I want accounts from the WP site to be cloned to the ST site, and the ST SSO seems to do that.

Comment: A lot of them have IDP integration for LDAP/AD. I know CAS, Shibboleth and SAML support iDP integration.  It really depends on the scale you need to run at.  CAS is probably the most robust out of the box solution with connectors to just about everything you can imagine but its a little involved to get setup and running.  Any centralized user management / iDP is going to provide the cross account functionality.  You may need to create a WP plugin for auth, but many already exist.  If these Smarter Tools guys published their protocol, you could just write an implementation in PHP.

Comment: Could I just redirect a new user registration on WP to some page that can set an asp.net authcookie? If I did that, couldn't I utilize the built-in SSO functionality mentioned? Since it seems to utilize cookies in order to enable SSO.

Comment: Absolutely, there are hooks in the plugins for this sort of stuff.  IIRC I use to work on a wordpress ldap/ad plugin that did this very thing.  You can probably find it on SF or elsewhere and make it work for your situation.

Comment: But doesn't it have to be a certain type of cookie that the ASP.NET app can use? Here is the documentation for using cookies to authenticate users via SSO in the ASP.NET app. http://help.smartertools.com/SmarterTrack/current/Default.aspx?qq=%2fSmarterTrack%2fcurrent%2fTopics%2fInstallation%2fExternalProviders.aspx It's called GetSignInCookieInfo Method on that page.

Comment: You can have the account creation go to an asp page. For authentication, things will be more difficult. If you really want to use the SmartTracker auth, you can create an auth service in .net and post across to it from WordPress via the plugin and curl. You will probably want some kind of rate limiting on that endpoint.